# Odd behavior of ArrayReshape with SparseArrays

Tags: list-manipulation, sparse-arrays

I am trying to understand why I am seeing inconsistent results when using `ArrayReshape` on a `SparseArray` vs. a normal nested `List`. For example, define a sample 2x2x2x2 array and its `SparseArray` representation (which needn't be actually sparse):

```
Matrix = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 2}];
SparseMatrix = SparseArray@Matrix;
```

Both `Dimensions@Matrix` and `Dimensions@SparseMatrix` give `{2,2,2,2}` as expected. However, while

```
Dimensions@ArrayReshape[Matrix, {4, 4}]
```

gives `{4, 4}` as expected, in my system (clean 11.2.0.0 kernel on Windows 10) running

```
Dimensions@ArrayReshape[SparseMatrix, {4, 4}]
```

gives `{8, 2}`, which is quite odd. Is this a bug, or expected behavior? am I missing something here?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue with version 11.3 for macOS. The exprected behavior is of course an array of dimensions `{4, 4}`.

Comment: version 9.0 (Windows 10 64 bit) also gives `{4,4}`.

Comment: ... and so does version 11.0.1 for macOS.

Comment: And both v10.4 and v11.3 on Linux give the correct answer, `{4, 4}`, for both instances.